# How can I test Joomla performace

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, apache, wpo, cms-testing

After searching a lot over the web, I found nothing about my issue.
Its there any tool that can test my Joomla website/server performance?!

I am searching for a tool that test the website how it will react when having a lot of visitors.
What apache and mysql would do in those cases...

Comment: http://jmeter.apache.org/index.html , http://gatling.io/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing Joomla site speed](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9032/testing-joomla-site-speed)

Answer (score 3):

For website performance test you can use some online service like:

- http://www.webpagetest.org/
- http://tools.pingdom.com/
- https://gtmetrix.com/
- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

For server/application you can try with one of this posible solutions:

- http://newrelic.com/php/joomla
- https://loadimpact.com/

Regards.